# How to add a custom form in a project tab panel plugin (Jira SDK)

Tags: sdk, jira, tabpanel

I'm using the latest Jira SDK and Jira version (currently 6.x).

I'm able to create a Project tab panel plugin and display a form in the velocity template, but I would like to save data when a user post this form and also retreive the saved data to populate the form on display.

What should I use to read and write data from my "project tab panel" ?

---

More information about our needs for this plugin :

- The purpose of the plugin is to store speicific information about our Jira projects in a custom tab so that everybody can see it (ex : customer, who's the project manager, etc.)
- Also, any user should be able to fill the information and edit it later. Everybody see the same information.
- The stored data is not read only, it should be possible to edit it
- We'll need some validation on a couple of fields
- The data could be accessed by everybody to start. But it's possible that we'll have to secure it later. If it's the case, we'll completely hide the tab panel if the user doesn't have access.

Comment: *You are free to accept an answer, if it helped you and you don't have any more questions.  **:)**  Otherwise feel free to ask.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Active Objects](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Active+Objects) (recommended) or [Plugin Data Storage](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Store+and+retrieve+plugin+data).

```
If this does not help you enough, I need more specific information like:
   - Does one user store data, which should be available to everybody?
   - Does a user save data only for himself?
   - Should the stored data be read-only or writable?
   - Should the stored data be accessible only by few users (e.g. with specific rights)?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added some details :)
One of the difficulty I have is to find what I should do with my "project tag panel plugin" for it to be able to post and retreive data from the request. Should I submit data to a "webwork action" or another type of "plugin" with ajax? Or is my "project tab panel" class able to retreive and validate a post? Should I implement a specific class? I've seen the plugin data storage example, but it's a servlet. Do I have to create a Servlet and then redirect to my "tab panel" (I guess not)?

Comment: Isn't the project lead your project manager?
Maybe [Profields](http://www.deiser.com/subject/portfolio/plugins/profields/) is what your looking for?

If you really want to do it yourself, you would need a [webwork action](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Webwork+Actions). The view can be the same as your default view. Adding validation and permission control is another thing, but there are a lot of tutorials for that.

Comment: The project lead was just an example. I guess it would make more sense to add a panel in the project administration screen like how the version tab works (when you click "manage versions", you are redirected to a the administration section).

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you: [Creating an Admin Configuration Form](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Creating+an+Admin+Configuration+Form) or [Creating Project Templates](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+Project+Templates+with+the+project-template+Module).
For just adding some information, you can simply use the projects (long) description.
For "custom fields" for projects plus validation, I already suggested a plugin - at least take a look as an inspiration.  ;)
No offence, but you seem to lack some basics. Try doing some more tutorials.

Comment: If you continue your search [more specific now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669708/how-to-add-a-webwork1-action-linked-to-a-project-admin-tab-in-jira) rewarding my effort here would be a nice thing to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API module](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/rest-api-development/rest-plugin-module) to expose your APIs and then do ajax requests to POST and GET your data. This is a good solution for building add-ons on a "single page application" fashion.

Cheers.